Config MSBuild to generate output directories based on configuration
I'm working on a MSBuild project. I want to generate my output files into folders like this:
C:\PATH\TO\PROJECT
│   wincat.c
│   wincat.h
│   wincat.vcxproj
│
└───build
    ├───Debug
    │   │   wincat.exe
    │   │   (other stuff)
    │   │
    │   └───wincat.tlog
    │
    └───Release
        │   wincat.exe
        │   (other stuff)
        │
        └───wincat.tlog


My wincat.vcxproj:
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="Current"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
            <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
            <Platform>Win32</Platform>
        </ProjectConfiguration>

        <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
            <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
            <Platform>Win32</Platform>
            

        </ProjectConfiguration>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
        <PlatformToolset>v143</PlatformToolset>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />

    <ItemGroup>
        <ClCompile Include="wincat.c" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ClInclude Include="wincat.h" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />

</Project>

So far, this is how I have done so far
msbuild ..\wincat.vcxproj /t:Build /p:OutDir=.\build\Release\,IntermediateOutputPath=.\build\Release\,Configuration=Release
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)


msbuild ..\wincat.vcxproj /t:Build /p:OutDir=.\build\Debug\,IntermediateOutputPath=.\build\Debug\,Configuration=Debug
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Is there anyway I can modify the vcxproj file so that I can type my command line shorter like this
msbuild ..\wincat.vcxproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Debug
msbuild ..\wincat.vcxproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release

and still achieve the same result? Thanks in advance.

Did you try setting the BaseOutputPath property? e.g. In the <PropertyGroup>, add <BaseOutputPath>build</BaseOutputPath>. There is also BaseIntermediateOutputPath. e.g. <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>

@JonathanDodds I just tried it. Neither of them works for me.  They just generate an output folder outside the build folder. I also tried putting both relative path and absolute path on the value. None of them works.

The C++ project support doesn't always follow the standard conventions. However, your command line is setting properties. You can move the property definitions into the project file, e.g. <PropertyGroup><OutDir>build\$(Configuration)</OutDir></PropertyGroup>.
